# What forces cause strings to oscillate at constant frequencies?

Tags: forces, acoustics, string, vibrations

I was doing some physics research (rock n' rolling) and I noticed when I hit the guitar string violently, it was momentarily out of pitch but quickly returned to the correct frequency.

What forces are causing it to move to a constant frequency?  Why are said forces in equilibrium only at a constant frequency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plucked guitar string provides the 'correct' frequency when certain conditions are met (you can find the [full math derivation here](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284))

In particular the string deformation has to be small and the end-points that clamp the string have to be perfectly rigid.

When you pluck the string 'violently' these conditions are no longer met.

Due to normal friction the string loses energy quite quickly and the enters a regime as described above, where the frequency returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Strings can oscillate at any frequency. If a length of string is subject to boundary conditions at each end, then it can resonate (producing a stable standing wave) at only certain frequencies.